# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the 'AirlineWebAppContext' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have changed the Data Type of the two properties in my model from "Datetime" to "string".

so this exception is coming.
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the 'AirlineWebAppContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

The two properties I have changed as follow.

```
 public string Plane_LocTo { get; set; }
 public string Plane_LocFrom { get; set; }
```

My Model as follows.

```
 public class Plane_Schedule
    {   [Key]
        public int Plane_id { get; set; }
        public int PlaneSch_id { get; set; }
        public string Plane_LocTo { get; set; }
        public string Plane_LocFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time_Dep { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time_Arrive { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Ticket>Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have tried to update the database by writing Add-Migration NewPlaneTwo

```
namespace AirlineWebApp.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class NewPlaneTwo : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.Plane_Schedule", "Plane_LocTo", c => c.String());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Plane_Schedule", "Plane_LocFrom", c => c.String());
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.Plane_Schedule", "Plane_LocFrom", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Plane_Schedule", "Plane_LocTo", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
        }
    }
}
```

But the issue is still there. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: So you applied that migration by using `update-database`? Did it change the columns in your database?

Comment: No but there is another error coming.

Comment: SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.